# Simple program to find number of vowels in a string not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying my hand on JavaScript and my browser refuses to execute this program I have written using switch case function. The goal is to find the number of vowels in a string (consider all are in-putted in lower case)

When I click the 'submit' button the text from the box goes away but nothing happens. 
The alert "hello" also does not appear, so I'm assuming that the function is not even being executed.

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script>
   function vow(form)
    {
     alert("hello");
     var a = new Array(10);
     a = form.t1.value;
     var flag = 0;
     var i;

     for(i=0;i<10;i++)
       {
     switch (a[i])
      {
       case 'a':
       flag++;
       break;

       case 'e':
       flag++;
       break;

       case 'i';
       flag++;
       break;

       case 'o';
       flag++;
       break;

       case 'u';
       flag++;
       break;
      }
      }
  alert(flag);  
  }
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <form>

  <input type="text" name="t1">
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onClick="vow(this.form)"/>

  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using `;` instead of `:`.

```
case 'i';
      __^__
```

Same case for `o` and `u`.

### Update:

I also show a (memory intensive) alternative version:

```
var count = input.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length;
```

### Update:

```
var vow = function(str) {
    var matches = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
    var count = matches ? matches.length : 0;
    alert("'" + str + "' contains " + count + " vowel(s)");
    return false;
}​ ​
```

```
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onClick="return vow(this.form.t1.value)"/>
```

[You can see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/2QPN2/).

Comment: +1, for nice answer, but also `return false` is required to stop the form submission.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it much simpler.. E.g. remove the vowels from your input and check the length difference comparing to original string.

```
var count = input.length - input.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, '').length;
```

EDIT: Or even simpler, remove everything but vowels ;-)

```
function vow(form) {
    alert(form.t1.value.replace(/[^aeiou]/gi, '').length);
}​
```

Comment: better use the modifiers: gi to handle upper and lower cases.
For more on [RegExp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Answer (score 3):

A little improved version of your program:

```
function vow(form) {
    var a = form.t1.value;
        flag = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        switch (a[i]) {
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
                flag++;
                break;
        }
    }
    alert(flag);
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b36D6/

But this task can be handled much simplier:

```
function vow(str) {
    return --(str.split(/[aeiou]/).length);
}
```

So: `vow("hello!")` -> 2

Comment: +1 as it looks elegant. @dfsq I don't think I understand how it works.. 
Could you elaborate a little.

Comment: Here's my guess. `--a` would be processed as `a=a-1` and then `a` would be processed. But with `--(str.split(/[aeiou]/).length)` -> how does Javascript decide it should perform: `str.length - str.split(/[aeiou]/).length`

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the vow method to

```
function vow(form) {
  a = form.t1.value;

  var matches = a.toString().match(/[aeiou]/g);

  if( matches != null){
    alert(matches.length);
  } else {
    alert(0);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used

```
case 'i'; case 'o'; case 'u';
```

should be

```
case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
```

and also use return false at the end of your function, like

```
function vow(form)
{

    // code
    return false;
}
```

and also add `return` like

```
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onClick="return vow(this.form)"/>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hwp6W/2/).

Answer (score 0):

> [OP] When I click the 'submit' button the text from the box goes away but nothing happens. The alert "hello" also does not appear, so I'm assuming that the function is not even being executed.

You need to user onSubmit event instead of the onClick handler as follows:

```
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" onSubmit ="vow(this.form)"/>
```