# How to get total number of vowels in a string

Tags: javascript

I am just curious how you can get the total number of vowels in a string. I know this is a very simple function, but I am new to Javascript. Thanks for the help

Comment: You can iterate over the characters of the string and increase a counter for each character that is a vowel. Or you could use a regular expression and count the matches.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Сounting vowels in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14912935/218196).

Comment: and [Simple program to find number of vowels in a string not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12921195/218196)

Answer (score 3):

You can remove all characters that are not vowels and count the remaining ones:

```
var str = /* something*/,
numberVowels = str.replace(/[^aeiou]/ig, '').length;
```

Where

- `/[^aeiou]/` matches single character NOT present in the list "aeiou"
- `i` is the case-insensitive flag, to count AEIOU too.
- `g` is the global flag, to replace ALL characters which are not vowels, instead of just the first one.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one question, what is the ig for??

Comment: @user2684242 `ig` are flags, I have updated with explanation. Also see [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for full information.

Comment: Now I would use `(str.match(/[aeiou]/ig) || []).length`.